# How to model Database where a table entry can refer to another entry in the same table

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a web app, being used by engineers for Asset(machines, scales) calibrations on a Site & certificate can be generated based on those readings. Up till now, the requirement was so that for a given `SITE` includes multiple `ASSET` and each asset has its own `CALIBRATION`.

So had my Modal like this.

[image]

With a recent change to include a new type of certificate. Where an `ASSET` can have multiple calibration (Two to be exact) one before Adjustment and One after if needed.

My question is, what is the best way to accommodate this change? Should I change the relation between `ASSET` one-to-one `CALIBRATION` to one-to-many with multiplicity (1..2) which basically requires to change lot of code check. or should adding another column in `ASSET` table which points to another entry within the same table. Or is there any other approach to opt ?

I'm using ASP.MVC, with Entity Framework.

**Mapping**

```
public Report_AssetMap()
{
    HasKey(one => one.report_asset_id);

    // Site_Report one-to-many-rel Report_Asset 
    HasRequired(one => one.Site_Report).WithMany(one => one.Report_Assets).HasForeignKey(one => one.site_report_id);

    // Report_Asset one-to-one-rel Asset_Calcert
    HasOptional(one => one.Asset_Calcert).WithRequired(ad => ad.Report_Asset).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}

public Asset_CalcertMap()
{
    HasKey(one => one.report_asset_id);

    // User one-to-many Asset_Calcert (with nullable Calcert_handled_by_id at many End)
        HasOptional(o => o.Calcert_Handled_By).WithMany(r => r.Handled_Calcert).HasForeignKey(o => o.calcert_handled_by_id);

}
```

Comment: One asset has two calibrations. Bite the bullet and make the model reflect that. Adding a calibration doesn't multiply an asset. If you go that path you'll always have trouble finding distinct assets.

Comment: Agreed, But 1-to-1 relationship of `ASSET` & `CALIBRATION` i've `report_asset_id` as PK on Asset's table and same named `report_asset_id` as PK & FK on Calibration's table. Wouldn't changing the schema can cause a lose in my Data ? As mentioned i'm using EF6-Code First approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a separate table for each of the pre and post adjustment certs; this is a solid use case for table-per-concrete-class inheritance (which is not yet included in EF Core but I'm guessing you're using EF6).  Put common properties in a base class, derive a class for your pre and post adjustment certs (can be empty if no differentiation other than table names), then `MapInheritedProperties` and specify different table names for the derived classes in the model configuration.

https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

If you then want to query against all `Asset_CalCert`s, you can specify a single `DbSet<Asset_Caclert>` `DbSet` in the `DbContext` to query while your `Report_Asset` entity can have a property referencing each derived `Asset_CalCert` type.

In this way you can keep your 1:? relationship while maintaining the ability to query all `Asset_CalCert`s as though they were in a single table.

Comment: Well it makes sense but for a live DB how do I handle the data lose adding these migration?

Comment: You should be able to keep the original table and entity and only derive the new “post adjustment cert table from the original entity.